# Como consultar el primer valor obtenido de cada fecha en una semana en PostgreSQL y convertirlo en un Array-JSON

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Como indica la pregunta, deseo obtener el primer valor obtenido de cada fecha de una tabla que posee N cantidad de items y columnas pero posee un campo `timestamp without time zone` y dichos valores los deseo concatenar en un JSON el cual este dentro de un Array. A la tabla solo se le pasa el intervalo de fecha de incio y de fin (tipo `DATE` ambos). La bd esta hecha en postgresql 9.4

```sql
ID | fecha               
1   "2019-05-18 13:55:54"
2   "2019-05-18 13:57:22"
3   "2019-05-18 13:57:37"
4   "2019-05-18 13:58:07"
5   "2019-05-18 13:58:37"
6   "2019-05-18 13:58:48"
7   "2019-05-19 13:55:54"
8   "2019-05-19 13:57:22"
9   "2019-05-19 13:57:37"
10  "2019-05-20 13:58:07"
11  "2019-05-20 13:58:37"
12  "2019-05-20 13:58:48"
```

El objetivo final seria que la respuesta la obtenga en una sola columna y tener algo similar a `[{"id" : 1, "fecha" :"2019-05-18 13:55:54"},{"id" : 7, "fecha" :"2019-05-19 13:55:54"},{"id" : 10, "fecha" :"2019-05-20 13:58:48"}]`

Ya poseo una noción de como obtener el JSON que busco dentro del Array, pero aún no se me ocurre como obtener el primer registro de cada día.

He pensado en usar el `min` con el `group by` pero aún no tengo una idea clara

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes usar funciones ventanas para obtener tu caso min() over (), además utilizar las funciones row_to_json y json_agg pata darle el formato requerido,   en tu caso algo como esto:

```
create table tabla (id int, fecha timestamp without time zone );

insert into tabla  values
(1,   '2019-05-18 13:55:54'),
(2,   '2019-05-18 13:57:22'),
(3,   '2019-05-18 13:57:37'),
(4,   '2019-05-18 13:58:07'),
(5,   '2019-05-18 13:58:37'),
(6,   '2019-05-18 13:58:48'),
(7,   '2019-05-19 13:55:54'),
(8,   '2019-05-19 13:57:22'),
(9,   '2019-05-19 13:57:37'),
(10,  '2019-05-20 13:58:07'),
(11,  '2019-05-20 13:58:37'),
(12,  '2019-05-20 13:58:48');


 select json_agg(row_to_json(dat2)) from 
 (
 select id, fecha from 
 (
 select id, fecha,  min(fecha) over (  partition by fecha::date )  from tabla
 ) as dat  where fecha=min
 ) as dat2;
```

resultado:

```
  [{"id":1,"fecha":"2019-05-18T13:55:54"}, {"id":7,"fecha":"2019-05-19T13:55:54"}, {"id":10,"fecha":"2019-05-20T13:58:07"}]
```

(1 fila)